# How can I change the space between two \cvmetaevent?

Tags: spacing, vspace

How can I reduce the space between two `\cvmetaevent`? The codes are the following

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    CV META EVENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Renders a CV event on the sidebar
% param 1: title
% param 2: subtitle (optional)
% param 3: customer, employer, etc,. (optional)
% param 4: info text (optional)
\newcommand{\cvmetaevent}[4] {
    \textcolor{maincol} {\cvtext{\textbf{\begin{flushleft}#1\end{flushleft}}}}
     
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}{
    \textcolor{darkcol} {\cvtext{\textbf{#2}} }
    }

    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}{}{
        \cvtext{{ \textcolor{darkcol} {#3} }}\\
    }

    \cvtext{#4}\\[14pt]
}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   QR CODE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Renders a qrcode image (centered, relative to the parentwidth)
% param 1: percent width, from 0 to 1
\newcommand{\cvqrcode}[1] {
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width={#1}\mpwidth]{qrcode}
    \end{center}
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: So, it does not. Could you please write the codes?

Comment: \cvsection{ACHIEVEMENTS}

\cvmetaevent {CSIR-UGC NET, December, 2014}   
{Life Sciences}{Rank-23(LS)}
 
\cvmetaevent {ICMR-JRF,2015}{Life Sciences}{Rank-91}
{}

Comment: Than make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and put a `%` at the end of each line within that command.

Comment: Can I reduce the space between \cvmetaevent {CSIR-UGC NET, December 2014} {Life Sciences}{Rank-23(LS)} and \cvmetaevent {ICMR-JRF,2015}{Life Sciences}{Rank-91} {} by inserting a \hspce{} command between them?

Comment: @Maynak: Can you update your post/code to include a complete document that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing? The code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` (which it currently doesn't; currently it's just a code snippet). Can you do that?